# Interrupt while loop by a boolean condition

Tags: java, android, while-loop

I have a while loop that should stop as soon as the value of the Boolean variable is modified:

I made this variable to be changed by Another Activity containing AsyncTask:

I tested it in several ways, but the while condition loop is infinite, I can never get the "It's Ready!" message displayed, it seems to me that the while loop is not aware of the ready variable changes.

AnotherActivity.java

```java
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    MainActivity.ready=true;
...........
```

MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static boolean ready = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    verifyReady();
}

private void verifyReady() {
    while(!ready){
    //do nothing
}

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"It's Ready!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
...........
```

Can someone help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: please add complete code of async task class as well

Comment: add `volatile` to ready's definition. This will force your loop to not cache the value in the loop

Comment: @Rodrigo just making sure... have you fired the AsyncTask ?

Comment: @Abdul Whaheed, i'll add when i back to my home.

Comment: @ControlAltDel thanks, studying now your suggestion.

Comment: @THGRoy yes, there are more functions coming from AsyncTask that I get perfectly.  My MainActivity updates itself with data coming from AsyncTasc, but the while loop condition never breaks.